# What does "Multimedia/Gaming Environment" setting do for some Wifi adapters?

Tags: wireless-networking

On Windows, when using some Wifi adapters, in device properties > advanced tab, you'll see a setting called "Multimedia/Gaming Environment", it is disabled by default and you can enable it if you like.

I tested it myself and found enabling this will sometimes result in a slightly lower link-layer speed, but also slightly less packet loss.

Googling it will show up a lot of different explain for it, some says it's QOS, some says it lower the buffer, some says it's a frame burst technology, some says it allow more connections, some says it lower the ping, some says it trys to maintain a constant ping.....

So what does this setting actually do, officially?

Comment: First it's a unique feature to your hardware, second yes, its QOS and deals with bufferbloat

Comment: I don't get it. Why was this question closed as too broad? It asked about a specific feature, how more "limited to a specific problem with enought detailto identify an adequate answer" can it be?